# User input params issue

Tags: c++, c

I've been going crazy these past few hours on this little bit of code lol. I'm trying to get the full string input from the user, but its only printing the first word they type, for example: if they type 'REPORT HELLO TEST', only 'HELLO' is displayed and nothing else. So I figured I'd post it here and see what can come of it.

```
static void ns_cmd_report(sourceinfo_t *si, int parc, char *parv[])
{
    myuser_t *mu;
    mynick_t *mn = NULL;
    hook_user_req_t req;


    char *reason = parv[0];


    if (!reason){

        command_fail(si, fault_needmoreparams, STR_INSUFFICIENT_PARAMS,     "REPORT");
        command_fail(si, fault_needmoreparams, "Syntax: REPORT <Reason>");
        return;
    }

    logcommand(si, CMDLOG_REGISTER, "(BUG REPORT) - Message: \2%s\2", reason);

    command_success_nodata(si, "Your bug report has been successfully sent.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: How is the user input being read in?

Comment: it supposed to be a custom module for Atheme IRC services.  They type /msg nickserv report msg) so pretty much an IRC Client.

Comment: I dont see the input being made, but if you are working with an `std::string` the you can use `getline` by including `<string>`. This is for C++, at least

Comment: I'm guessing that the arguments (*parv[]) are being split by spaces. ie. REPORT HELLO TEST, parv[0] = "HELLO", parv[1] = "TEST"....

Comment: I don't think its C++, its more like C# imo @ArchieGertsman.

Comment: Thats exactly the issue @codersl

Comment: @Matt it's not C#. There are pointers being used.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman you can use pointers in C# but it's really not recommended - [unsafe C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan i know, and for that reason, you wouldnt see something like this in C#

Comment: My point was are they specified on the command line or being read in using a method?  If on the command line, the shell would split the arguments by spaces.  To have all words read in as a single argument, you would have to put quotes around it.

Comment: C#? C++? C? They're three different languages. The question doesn't seem to be language-agnostic so please choose one.

Comment: Decide in which language you want to program.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i think your problem is in the understanding
static void ns_cmd_report(sourceinfo_t *si, int parc, char *parv[])

if this like java, i never use it in c++,
the (int parc) is your parameter counter so check if this is not 1 when you call for it.
and char* parv[] is your character parameter value array, and you should enter the first arg in parv[0] second in parv[1] and so on.

so try this.
but i am not sure

Comment: Sorry, -1. The answer is poorly formatted and you're talking about one of `main`'s signatures which is clearly not the case here because it's a custom function and we don't know how it's called. Also, you shouldn't post answers if you're "not sure".

Comment: sorry, but how can i delete this answer

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible if it's been accepted.